# Xml parsing and conversion to json using backbone.js

Tags: json, xml, backbone.js

I'am new to Backbone.js. I have a XML file something like the following. I want to convert this to JSON object using Backbone.js. Measurement is a list type . Parsing is also needed. Please help me out with this.

```
<Counter name="">
    <measurement name="" abc="" xyz=""></measurement>
    <measurement name="" abc="" xyz=""></measurement>
    <measurement name="" abc="" xyz=""></measurement>
</Counter>
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried already?

Comment: iam new to backbone js. unaware of it.Please provide suggestions.tried this link.http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/ULK7q/. But didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to backbonejs as well and had the same issue. When we do `this.fetch();` we need to set dataType to xml

```
this.fetch({ 
  dataType: "xml", 
  async: true, 
  success: function(collection, xml) { .... }
});
```

But there is also one catch, you have to parse to output into a typical javascript object. (jQuery.parseXML() may come in handy in such case)

Also providing a sample of your code will also help us debug the issue.

Comment: xml file to be uploaded from UI side and to be parsed and validated(well-formed or not).Iam not fetching it from server.